# update ASCII character in mysql

Tags: mysql, character

I'm storing ASCII character in mysql but while update record, ASCII character convert to symbol  character!

For store:

```
<textarea id="post_entry" class="text" cols="90" rows="18" name="post_entry"></textarea>
```

```
$post_entry = $_POST['post_entry'];
docommand("INSERT INTO post (post_entry) VALUES('".$post_entry."')");
```

For Update:

```
<textarea id="post_entry_edit" class="text" cols="90" rows="18" name="post_entry_edit"><?php echo $row['post_entry']; ?></textarea>
```

```
$post_entry_edit = $_POST['post_entry_edit'];
docommand("UPDATE post SET post_entry='$post_entry_edit' WHERE id = '$post_id'");
```

Comment: What character encodings/collations do you use?

Comment: UTF8 / utf8_persian_ci

Comment: Which characters are affected?

Comment: Characters Code, Exp: & l t ; h t m l & g t;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem resolved

```
<?php
$raw_html = $row['post_entry'];
$to_textarea = preg_replace('/&(\w+;)/', '&amp;$1', $raw_html );
?>
<textarea id="post_entry_edit" class="text" cols="90" rows="18" name="post_entry_edit"><?php echo $to_textarea; ?></textarea>
```

[Source](http://lars.st0ne.at/blog/prevent+decoding+of+html+entities+in+textareas)